How can I swap the Merge Join inputs without crashing SSIS?
I have chosen SSIS for SQL Server 2016 since my SSIS Server is just 2016 anyway (SELECT @@VERSION gives Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR) (KB5029187) - 13.0.7029.3 (X64)). Perhaps a younger SSIS does not have the issue - that would already be an answer to this question. But if not, I wonder whether this is something linked to settings that I can change or whether this is a bug.

How can I avoid crashing SSIS when clicking on "Swap Input" in a "Merge Join" component?

Looks like a bug.
Make sure you have installed SP3 and all the later updates (Full details here: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2016x.
But if the bug is still there when running the latest version, you are out of luck: SQL Server 2016 is out of support.

Your answer looks like a guess. I will not take the effort and update the system only to find out the answer. I need someone else from a newer version to tell me, or to tell me how to avoid it in the older version. I may think of installing the latest SP3 of 2016 if someone knows that it fixes bugs like this, but I won't do it for a test.

Why exactly did you not install SP3? There are reasons why it was released. If you don't apply the product updates, you will run into all bugs that the updates fixed. Not applying updates (to a 10-years old software, even!) is just bad practice.

I will not take the effort and update the system good luck, then.

I checked the version of the SSIS server and found that it has already SP3. Thus, the bug is not fixed by the latest 2016 update. I put the version in the question to make that clear.
